# How to run Lineage 2 on Ubuntu?

Tags: 11.10, wine

I can't run Lineage2 on Ubuntu 11.10.

Does anyone know the solution, how to start it? What do I need to do to get it work. When I start `L2.exe`, it doesn't open or do anything or it opens with no buttons in the game.

Help please.

Answer (score 3):

Almost every windows application/game can run on linux using an emulator/compatibility layer program.In that case,Wine seems to be the ideal solution.

Wine is a program that lets you,as I said above,run Windows games and apps.

Type in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

or go to Ubuntu Software Center and search for **Wine**.Then click **install**.

After installing right click the exe file of your game and click open With Wine Windows Compatibility Layer.Then the program will install and you will be running it on your ubuntu.

You can also check the page for Lineage 2 on the [official wine website](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2273).

Answer (score 0):

You need to also make the exe executable.

Comment: "Or it opens with no buttons in the game"--sometimes it starts, but improperly. Permissions shouldn't cause such an issue.